# javascript regex how to match only parts in a list with mandatory prefix

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match ": red", ": 10", ": [special]" only if category present before (I want to use replace function to get rid of them afterwards)

```
category fruit(color: red, size: 10, others: [special])
```

I have this regex for above

```
(((:\s*[\w\[\]]+)(?=[,\)]))+)
```

except for category, I can't seem to be able to use lookbehind for that.

Comment: What format is the list in? I want to assume this is json or a .js object, but it's not formatted correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we take the the following input **verbatim**:

**Figure I - Input String**

```
category fruit(color: red, size: 10, others: [special])
```

Using a positive lookbehind to match literal `: red`, `: 10`, and `: [special]`:

**Figure II**

```js
/(?<=category[\S\s]+?)(:\s?red|:\s?10|:\s?\[special\])/g
```

**Figure III**

| Segment | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `(?<=category[\S\s]+?)` | Match, **but do not consume**, literal "categorey", anything in between if it proceeds... |
| `(:\s?red|:\s?10|:\s?\[special\])` | ...literal colon, zero to one space, literal "read" OR literal colon, zero to one space, literal "10" OR literal colon, zero to one space, literal "[special]" |

See [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sGA8oz/1)

<sup>Jeffery Flynt commented that it isn't syntactically correct, I'd have to agree</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match word characters before the colon and either word characters after the colon or from`[...]`, and the values have to be between parenthesis, then you might also use:

```
(?<=\bcategory\s[^()]*\([^()]*\w):\s*(?:\w+|\[[^\[\]]*\])(?=[^()]*\))
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind assertion, check what is to the left is:

  - `\bcategory\s+[^()]*` Match the word category, followed by whitespace chars and optionally any char except parenthesis
  - `\([^()]*\w` Match `(` and again any char except parenthesis followed by a word char
- `)` Close the lookbehind
- `:\s*` Match `:` and optional whitespace chars
- `(?:\w+|\[[^\[\]]*\])` Match either 1+ word chars, or match from `[...]`
- `(?=[^()]*\))` Positive lookahead, assert `)` to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZIwSn7/1)